# Keyword re-use in header <h1> and <h2> tags - best practices

Tags: html

I have a company profile with multiple tabs.  Is it advisable to re-use the company name in the h1 and h2 header tags.  For example

American Express is the -- h1

And then there are tabs about Earnings, Management Team, Stock Ratings, etc.

Should the tabs have h2 tags which read:

American Express Earnings
American Express Management Team
etc

OR should they be without the company name repeated given the co. name has the H1 header, e.g.,:

Earnings
Management Team
etc

Would google consider option 1 keyword stuffing of some variety or would Google better crawl the pages more as it knows what is on them?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

There is a point in having the company name in the title, description and header if it's what the page is about. Preferrably they should describe the page and also be different for each page. Repating the company name in every header on the page just to make it appear many times is pointless.

Search engines is looking for real content in pages, so if your headers makes sense for a human, the search engines are likely to find it reasonable too.